# What am I doing wrong?- Differential equations and Integrals

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find an equation for $\int x^x dx = h$

(I've not been told it's impossible... so I tried to... just to for fun)

So we know that $f^{g(x)}(x) = h(x)$ where $g(x) = k$ (constant)

so: $h'(x) = k \cdot f^{k-1} $

$x^x = h'(x) = k \cdot f^{k-1}(x)$

and thus:  $f(x) = (\dfrac{x^x}{c}) ^ {\dfrac{1}{c-1}}$

and if we substitude back "f(x)" we get:
$h(x) = ((\dfrac{x^x}{c}) ^ {\dfrac{1}{c-1}})^{c} = (\dfrac{x^x}{c}) ^ {\dfrac{c} {c-1}}$

and we get that: $\int x^x dx = h(x) = (\dfrac{x^x}{c}) ^ {\dfrac{c}{c-1}}$

but it doesn't work out for let's say $c=2$ or $c=3$ ...  any ideas why?
I am new to this field of maths.

Comment: Evaluating that integral is a nightmare, and one that really can't be done using standard math functions...You'd have a better bet using a series expansion to integrate.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Ok, thanks! I'm new to this kind of derivatives, and integrations and differential equations... :( however, I can't spot the mistake I've done here... any idea? from my perspective I've done everything "ok"

Comment: how comes that one time you have $\int x^x=h'$ and $\int x^x=h $ ?

Comment: @Isham my mistake, but finally you get that if: $\int x^x dx = f^k$  
then: $x^x = k f^{k-1}$

Comment: then $$x^x=kf^{k-1}f'$$  and not $x^x=kf^{k-1}$

Comment: @Isham Oh!!!!! Dang, how did I forget this?! thanks!

Comment: yep f is a function of x...dont forget it's derivative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, this really can't be done using standard integration techniques, but with a series expansion$$\int{x^xdx} = \int{e^{\ln x^x}dx} = \int{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k\ln^k x}{k!}}dx$$

As to what is wrong with your proof,

> $f^{g(x)}(x)=h(x)$ where $g(x)=k$ (constant)

This is completely wrong. Why would $g(x)$ be a constant? What does it even mean to raise a function to another function? I don't really know what you've done here, but it is definitely incorrect.

Comment: function raised to another function is my "general" presentation of a function. it could be anything

Comment: @OUR That isn't a thing. I don't know what you mean by "general" presentation, but that's some false maths right there

Comment: Why is it wrong? I mean, you can give me a function, any function and I will be able to present it in this f^g form, no?

Comment: @OUR I presume you mean $f^g(x)$. Even so, $g(x)$ is most definitely not a constant. Rather, $g(x)=x$

Comment: why? g(x) = const is a function... isn't it? I mean, let's take $x^4$ , 
then in that case: $f = x$ and $g = 4$  
however, if we take $4^x$,  then things flip around... (by f is mean f(x) and by g I mean g(x) and f^g = f^g(x) (x) )

Comment: @OUR but $x^x=x^4$ at only one point, i.e., $x=4$. I don't get the point.

Comment: No no, let's leave  $x^x$ behind for a second, we are talking about how I present a function, in that case, I present a general function as func1 raised to func2, and I can "build" any function using this form... (except weird ones like x! etc)

Comment: @OUR You can't do this...at all. Who told you this is possible? This is possible for a tiny minority of functions. Why would assume $h$ can be separated as such?

Comment: Oh, dang, what if we want x^2 + x ? it's not possible with f^g ... you're right.. didn't think about it... well at least I tried :D

Comment: @OUR, hey, no problem! We all goof up sometimes. Keep learning more though, there's a lot of fun stuff ahead.

Comment: wait, it is! $f = \sqrt{x^2 + x}$ and $g = 2 $ ain't it? why is it not possible? :(

Comment: @OUR Try $x=-\frac12$. See what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The integral $\int x^x dx$ cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. It requires a special function :

https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

$$\int x^x dx=\text{Sphd}(1\,;\,x)+\text{constant}$$
$$\int_0^x t^t dt=\text{Sphd}(1\,;\,x)$$
$\text{Sphd}(\alpha,x)$ is a non-standard special function.

Some properties and series expansions are provided in the paper referenced above.

Comment: OK got it! thanks <3 :)